# Passe Two parametrs in Router Angular2

Tags: parameters, angular

It is possible to passes two params in the router to one component

```
    this._router.navigate(['Dest', {'id1': 1},{'id2': 2}])


{path: '/dest/:id1/:id2', component: DestComponent, name: 'Dest'}
```

thanks for helping

Comment: did you try ```this._router.navigate(['Dest', {'id1': 1, 'id2': 2}])``` ?

Comment: yes but it not working 
I get as error hi dont know id2 from the path
there is an other solution ?

Comment: What router are you using? RC.1 router or router-deprecated? Or beta.x?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
this._router.navigate(['dest/', 1, 2]);
```

[Documentation Router Angular2](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html)

Comment: how can I get my params in the Dest Component 
using routePram 
with wich name I will get it ?

Comment: You should pass params to navigate function in the same order you declared them in your @Routes section for 'Dest' route.

Comment: {path: '/dest/:id1/:id2', component: DestComponent, name: 'Dest'}

when I do that with the some order I get this exception
 EXCEPTION: Route generator for 'id2' was not included in parameters passed.
he dont recegnize the second params

Answer (score 0):

In the new router just

```
this._router.navigate(['dest/'+ 1 + '/' + 2])
```

Comment: I need to have a name for my params for getting this in Dest.component
for using it in other Request 
thanks

Comment: The name is in the route `id1`, `id2`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all I found the solutions

I have just a Syntaxe probleme

```
 this._router.navigate(['Dest', {'id1': 1,'id2': 2}])
```

instead of ---
 use without accolade

```
 this._router.navigate(['Dest', {'id1': 1},{'id2': 2}])

    {path: '/dest/:id1/:id2', component: DestComponent, name: 'Dest'}
```